# Contact info requirement after 5 minutes

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-events

I have a PHP site that the client would like to require the viewer to fill out and submit a contact form after viewing the site for 5 minutes.  Info does not need to be added to a database, just sent to their office email. I have created the form but am not sure of the best way to handle the pop-up and make it required before continuing to view the site.

Comment: Make it *required*? What a way to ensure all your visit lengths are < 5 minutes.

Comment: @Matt I get even more stupid requirements at my work :P

Comment: I suppose you could track a session value.  Set it to the current timestamp when a session starts, compare it to the current timestamp on every page request.  If the comparison exceeds 5 minutes, redirect to the form.  It's... not a very good user experience.  But I guess that's the problem of whoever defined the requirement.

Comment: And, it would be very easy to get around that kind of requirement without server-side intervention (simply reset the session by closing the browser). This kind of functionality also means that if a user returns to the site, they would have to re-enter their information after 5 min even if they already did previously. Very odd requirement. How do you handle javascript being turned off?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your client a significant disservice if you haven't tried to talk them out of this. If they want people not to visit the site, they should just not have it developed. If they want people to visit it (or ever come back) they shouldn't even consider this.

That being said, you could set up some sort of timer to "force" a popup to appear, but many popup blockers would handle that. There would be ways around any scheme like this, regardless of how you do it (cookies, serving a different page, etc.), but unless you've got something incredibly unique on that site, your client's readers probably won't even bother with them-they'll go to a site that isn't deliberately broken.

I would suggest to your client that they instead put in a box where users who WANT to be contacted can enter an email address. That won't annoy your users, but will still let you take in leads from those who are interested.

Comment: Love it - I totally agree - that's what I had been telling my client all along - glad to hear you are all backing me up. We'll see how it works out and thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you;

**PHP** for the website page

```
if (false === isset($_SESSION['startTime'])) {
     $_SESSION['formSubmitted'] = false;
     $_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
}
```

**PHP** for the jqueryCheck.php;

```
$return = 0;

if (false == $_SESSION['formSubmitted']) {
    if ((time() - $_SESSION['startTime']) > 300) {
        $showForm = 1;
    }
} else {
    $return = 2;
}

echo $return;
```

**PHP** after form submitted and validated

```
$_SESSION['formSubmitted'] = true;
```

**JQUERY**

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "jqueryCheck.php", success: function(showForm){
        switch (showForm) {
             case 0: //not yet at 5 mins and not submitted
             break;
             case 1:  //at 5 minutes no form submitted
                //code to show form
             break;
             case 2:  //form submitted
                 clearInterval ( intervalId );
             break; 
        }
    }});
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simply solution without Javascript.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['trial_end'])) {
    $_SESSION['trial_end'] = time() + 5 * 60;
}

// Check if trial has expired and we are not already on the form
if (time() > $_SESSION['trial_end'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/form') {
  header('Location: /form');
  exit;
}
```